# React code not showing in browser

Tags: html, webpack, reactjs

I'm using Webpack to bundle some React code written in JSX format. I have everything up and running as far as compiling goes and it looks as though every thing is correct in the `bundle.js` output file. When I import it into an HTML file and try to display the React code it doesn't show up for some reason. I've made a regular javascript file and included it in the `main.js` so that it is also included in the Webpack output file `bundle.js` and this does show up in the browser. So when the `bundle.js` is used in my html file I just get the text "Hello, im located in a seperate file" and not the React elements.

**React Code(main.js)**

```
require('./extra.js');

var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

ReactDOM.render(
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
    document.getElementById('example')
);
```

**Regular JS File(extra.js)**

```
document.write("Hello, im located in a seperate file");
```

**Output file after running webpack(bundle.js)**

```
/******/ (function(modules) { // webpackBootstrap
/******/    // The module cache
/******/    var installedModules = {};

/******/    // The require function
/******/    function __webpack_require__(moduleId) {

/******/        // Check if module is in cache
/******/        if(installedModules[moduleId])
/******/            return installedModules[moduleId].exports;

/******/        // Create a new module (and put it into the cache)
/******/        var module = installedModules[moduleId] = {
/******/            exports: {},
/******/            id: moduleId,
/******/            loaded: false
/******/        };

/******/        // Execute the module function
/******/        modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, __webpack_require__);

/******/        // Flag the module as loaded
/******/        module.loaded = true;

/******/        // Return the exports of the module
/******/        return module.exports;
/******/    }


/******/    // expose the modules object (__webpack_modules__)
/******/    __webpack_require__.m = modules;

/******/    // expose the module cache
/******/    __webpack_require__.c = installedModules;

/******/    // __webpack_public_path__
/******/    __webpack_require__.p = "";

/******/    // Load entry module and return exports
/******/    return __webpack_require__(0);
/******/ })
/************************************************************************/
/******/ ([
/* 0 */
/***/ function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

    __webpack_require__(1);

    React.render(React.createElement(
        "h1",
        null,
        "hello world"
    ), document.getElementById("app"));

    var HelloMessage = React.createClass({
        displayName: "HelloMessage",

        render: function () {
            return React.createElement(
                "div",
                null,
                "Hello ",
                this.props.name
            );
        }
    });
    ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(HelloMessage, { name: "John" }), mountNode);

/***/ },
/* 1 */
/***/ function(module, exports) {

    /**
     * Created by sf on 1/14/2016.
     */

    document.write("Hello, im located in a seperate file");

/***/ }
/******/ ]);
```

**HTML file im using the script in**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="example"></div>

<script src="bundle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think your first code block is cut off; mind fixing it?

Comment: Sorry about that, it's been corrected.

Comment: Why are there calls to both `React.render` and `ReactDOM.render`? Is there any error in the console? Are there imports for both of those (I don't see them in your code)? Where is `mountNode` defined?

Comment: They were just two examples I pulled off the React homepage I've simplified it. There are no errors anywhere.

Comment: If you look towards the bottom of the `bundle.js` file next to `__webpack__require__` it has (1) next to it. Does this mean it is missing a requirement possibly?

Comment: Please show the entire `main.js`. I'm not seeing any imports and it can't work without imports. And definitely use `ReactDOM.render`.

Comment: I assume require is equivalent to import. I have updated with your suggestion and I have tried using require previously per the React Websites getting started section still  didn't work, this is my entire main file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100696/discussion-between-after-sunset-and-josh-david-miller).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The examples on the [React homepage](http://facebook.github.io/react/) are not self-sufficient, but rather minimal examples of React itself. Here's how the example you're using might look, starting with `index.js`:

```js
var React = require( 'react' );
var ReactDOM = require( 'react-dom' );

var HelloMessage = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <div>Hello {this.props.name}</div>;
  }
});

var mountNode = document.getElementById( 'app' );
ReactDOM.render(<HelloMessage name="John" />, mountNode);
```

And your `index.html`:

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="./build/bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Notice that it is requiring a script called `bundle.js` and our source is called `index.js`. To transform the JSX and package our source into the bundle, we can use Webpack with this basic config:

```js
var webpack = require( 'webpack' );

module.exports = {
  context: __dirname + '/src',
  entry: './index.js',
  devtool: 'source-map',
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/build',
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },

  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        loaders: [ 'babel-loader?presets[]=react' ],
      }
    ],
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

you either need to put that script tag at the end of the body, or execute the code on document ready. when that script is running in the head, there isnt a div with id = app on the document yet

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app"></div>

  <script src="bundle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @After_Sunset Be sure to check that div id and that it matches your code exactly.

Comment: @bebraw Thanks for the advice, while trying debug this that was an issue at one point. I've since figured out a couple of issues and will write up a detailed answer.